# Vue does not update items in v-for from Vuex with dynamic component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

We have a dynamic component for `tab` body, which defined as

```
<component :is="currentTab.itemType" :itemId="currentTab.itemId"></component>
```

Template has a span, which reflects `itemId` - it changes every time when the `currentTab` changed in tabs host component.

Each component of `tab.itemType` has Vuex module, belongs to it specific type.

For example, there is store module `product` with described state:

```
{
  products: { [itemId: string]: IProduct }
}
```

When component created or `itemId` changed, it tries to run load action and put loaded product to `products` of vuex state.

So, there is Vue computed property, looks like

```
@State(productNamespace)
state: IProductState;

get currentProduct() {

  return this.state.products[this.itemId];
}
```

or even

```
@Getter(GetterNames.GET_PRODUCT_BY_ID, bindingOptions)
getProductById: (itemId: string) => IProduct;

get currentProduct() {

  return this.getProductById(this.itemId);
}
```

Each product has an `attributes` list, which is iterated by `v-for` with `:key`.

```
<v-list :key="itemId"><!-- itemId has no effect there -->
  <v-list-item v-for="attribute in currentProduct.attributes" :key="attribute.id">
    ...
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

The problem is:
when we change `itemId`, the attributes list displays all attributes from last added product and does not refresh it when switching to previous "tabs" with another `itemId` but the same `itemType`.

I've tried to set `:key` of parent `div` as `itemId` but with no effect.
When I set `:key` to `<component>`, vuex state becomes broken.

Vue version is 2.6.10

UPDATE:

It does not work with simple property of product too:

```
{{ currentProduct.name }}
```

Summary:

There is the `itemId` property in. And computed property which depends on it. So computed property does not reflect changes when `itemId` prop changed while Vuex collection does not changed.

Confirmed:

Computed property renews only when state.products collection changed. I've emulate this by run `createProduct` action for each tab switching. Collection in vuex state accepts unwatched product stub and reflect changes to legal `currentProduct` with given `itemId`

UPDATE 2: component with watcher. Still no way...

```
@Component
export default class Product extends Vue {

  @Prop({ type: Object, required: true })
  readonly tabItem: ITabItem;
    
  @State(productNamespace)
  state: IProductState;
    
  itemId: string;
    
  created() {
    
    //...
    this.initCurrentProduct();
  }

  // No changes until state.products was changed.   
  get currentProduct(): IProduct | {} {
    
    if (!this.state) return {};     
    return this.state.products[this.itemId];
  }
    
  @Watch('tabItem')
  onTabItemChanged()
  {
    DEBUG && console.log('Tab changed: keep moving!');
    this.initCurrentProduct();
  }
    
  private async initCurrentProduct() {

    const { isNew, itemId } = this.tabItem;

    if (itemId === this.itemId)
      return;

    DEBUG && console.log('ItemId changed.');
    this.itemId = itemId;

    // ...
  }
    
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing this.$store.state... instead of this.$state...?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I use 'vuex-class', so there is incorrect simplification. Just a minute, I  correct it.

Comment: As I remember Vuex recommends getters for computed properties, instead of direct access to Store. Have you tried using a getter?

Comment: Yes, original takes it from functional getter. It seems like only last item added reflect its properties, but switching back has no effect on computed properties with changed `itemId`. So I think there is `products` collection changed event raised.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same page here. Your'e saying that there's a getter but in the code shown you just access the store directly without any getter. Also the computed property is `get currentProduct() ` - why space? Is it in computed section?

Comment: It is a TypeScript version with Class Api. Getter looks like `[GetterNames.GetProductById](state) => (itemId) => state.products[itemId]`, it was omitted for simplify.

Comment: Ok, I don't know that version, so I won't try to answer this. However, I'm really confused, how your code actually looks like. I think you skip too much of your code and transform it too much "for simplicity". The way you have formulated your getter and the way it is called in the computed property can be crucial for understanding this problem. And you havn't provided that information.

Comment: currentTab seems to be not responsive - thus no update on change and therefore no update in computed etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the property you're passing to the dynamic component is `currentTab.itemId` which means itemId is actually an element in the `currentTab` object not the root Vue data object?

Vue does not track nested objects by default, it will only trigger redraw when the entire object is changed (for example if you do something like `currentTab = {...}`). You can either:

1. Use a watcher on `currentTab` with `deep: true` attribute: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch, and then trigger redraw with `this.$forceUpdate` whenever it is called.
2. Move `itemId` to the root of data and just update it from there

Comment: Updated the question with example of component with watcher and itemId as data. Still has no effect...But wait! Initial value of `itemId` is undefined, so it can't be reactive! Changed to default `itemId: string = '';` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

in your vuex mutation

```
let items = [...state.items]; // create a new copy

// mutate it 
items.map(item => item.selected = true);

// return the new copy
state.items = items;
```